# Is posible to do this? MONGODB MONGOOSE NODE.JS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Having this collection as a example

```
{ _id:1 ,hotelname:"hotelxd",rooms:17}
{ _id:2 ,hotelname:"hotelxd2",rooms:187}
```

I want to add a new field to this documents called hotel size that depends of the number of room with this conditions.

```
function classifyrhotel(rooms) {
if (rooms>=0 && rooms<=50) {
    return "Small hotel";
}
if (rooms>=51 && rooms<=100) {
    return "Medium hotel";
}
if (rooms>100) {
    return "Large hotel";
}
```

the final db should look like this

```
 { _id:1 ,hotelname:"hotelxd",rooms:17,hotelsize:"Small hotel"}
{ _id:2 ,hotelname:"hotelxd2",rooms:187,hotelsize:"Large hotel"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! You can use the aggregation pipeline with [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) stage and [$switch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/switch/) operator, then update your collection with [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) stage.

Here's the query :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      hotelsize: {
        $switch: {
          branches: [
            {
              case: {
                $lte: [
                  "$rooms",
                  50
                ]
              },
              then: "Small hotel"
            },
            {
              case: {
                $lte: [
                  "$rooms",
                  100
                ]
              },
              then: "Medium hotel"
            }
          ],
          default: "Large hotel"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $out: "collection"
  }
])
```

You can test it (without $out stage) [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/X0v_QTeLYx-)

**BEWARE** : this query will update you whole collection, try it before (removing the $out stage will perform the query without updating data)

**NOTICE** : As of MongoDB 4.2, you can perform [update operations](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#db.collection.update) with aggregation pipeline inside. This $addFields stage must do the job, but i can't test it right now.